# Function for checking operators in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I am trying to do a program which will identify operators in a string and display it. I want to know whether there is any function to check for an operator in string. Like we have `string.punctuation` for punctuation

I have tried putting some of the operators in a list and trying to compare it with the string.

```
op = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "<", ">", " ", "="]    
exp = input("Enter the expression: ")     
tokens = exp.split()     
for x in tokens:         
    if x in op:    
        print("operator: ", x)
```

I got the expected result, but just want to know whether there is a function available for checking an operator in string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any significantly better ways than what you did. But if you only want to check presence of the operators and performance is a consideration for you, I suggest using set intersection:

```
op = {"+","-","*","/","<",">"," ","="}
exp = input("""Enter the expression: """)     
tokens = set(exp)
print(tokens.intersection(op))
```

For input like `"+++ *** 2 < 3"` the printed value will be:

```
{' ', '+', '*', '<'}
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, this solution works for the given operators, but will not work as it is for multicharacter operators.

Comment: In that case, replacing `tokens = set(exp.split())` would address the issue. @afsantos. But the question seems to be concerning about single chars.